# What actually does system method removeBond() in Android?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I know, this method removes ble device/tag from list of bonded devices in android smartphone. But maybe he have other hidden functions, for example: send some commands to remove bond in ble device/tag side ?

How i can call method in android:

```
try {
    Method method = device.getClass().getMethod("removeBond", (Class[]) null);
    result = (boolean) method.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);
    if (result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Successfully removed bond");
    }
    return result;
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "ERROR: could not remove bond");
    e.printStackTrace();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: same issue in mi phone

Comment: yeah, I don't find any information about it, yet